# Code Producing Power::Infty

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, code-review, broken-code

I tried computing the following

```
Unprotect[C]
\[Psi] = Sqrt[2] - 1;
\[Epsilon] = .001;
\[Omega] = 50000;
k = 13;
j = 3;
    A1 = Flatten[
    Table[(s1^j)/(s2^k), {s2, 1, Floor[\[Omega]^(1/k)]}, {s1,Ceiling[((s2^k) (\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)], 
    Floor[((s2^k) (\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)] }]];
  A2 = Flatten[
    Table[(s1^j)/(s2^k), {s1, 1, Floor[\[Omega]^(1/j)]}, {s2, 
      Ceiling[((s1^j)/(\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/k)], 
      Floor[((s1^j)/(\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/k)]}]];
  A = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Intersection[A1, A2]]];
  C1 = DeleteDuplicates[
    Flatten[Table[(s1^j)/(2 s2 + 1)^k, {s2, 1, 
       Floor[(10 \[Omega])^(1/k)]}, {s1, 
       Ceiling[(((2 s2 + 1)^k) (\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)], 
       Floor[(((2 s2 + 1)^k) (\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)]}]]];
  C2 = DeleteDuplicates[
    Flatten[Table[(s1^j)/(2 s2 + 1)^k, {s1, 1, 
       Floor[(10 \[Omega])^(1/j)]}, {s2, 
       Ceiling[(((s1^j)/(\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/k) - 1)/2], 
       Floor[(((s1^j)/(\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/k) - 1)/2]}]]];
  C = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Intersection[C1, C2]]];
  g1 = N[Length[Intersection[A, C]]/Length[A]];
```

When `j=1` the code works fine but when `j` is an integer greater than `1`, it returns an error sign:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
```

I tried fixing it using `DeleteCases` to delete the zeros (see `t1` and `t2`)

```
Unprotect[C]
    \[Psi] = Sqrt[2] - 1;
    \[Epsilon] = .001;
    \[Omega] = 50000;
    k = 13;
    j = 3;
t1 = DeleteCases[
  Table[s1, {s1, Ceiling[((s2^k) (\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)], 
    Floor[((s2^k) (\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)]}], 0]
t2 = DeleteCases[
  Table[s2, {s2, Ceiling[((s1^j)/(\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/k)], 
    Floor[((s1^j)/(\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/k)]}], 0]
        A1 = Flatten[
        Table[(s1^j)/(s2^k), {s2, 1, Floor[\[Omega]^(1/k)]}, {s1,t1 }]];
      A2 = Flatten[
        Table[(s1^j)/(s2^k), {s1, 1, Floor[\[Omega]^(1/j)]}, {s2, 
         t2}]];
      A = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Intersection[A1, A2]]];
      C1 = DeleteDuplicates[
        Flatten[Table[(s1^j)/(2 s2 + 1)^k, {s2, 1, 
           Floor[(10 \[Omega])^(1/k)]}, {s1, 
           Ceiling[(((2 s2 + 1)^k) (\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)], 
           Floor[(((2 s2 + 1)^k) (\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)]}]]];
      C2 = DeleteDuplicates[
        Flatten[Table[(s1^j)/(2 s2 + 1)^k, {s1, 1, 
           Floor[(10 \[Omega])^(1/j)]}, {s2, 
           Ceiling[(((s1^j)/(\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/k) - 1)/2], 
           Floor[(((s1^j)/(\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/k) - 1)/2]}]]];
      C = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Intersection[C1, C2]]];
      g1 = N[Length[Intersection[A, C]]/Length[A]];
```

However, I continue to get `Power::Infty`.

How do we fix my code?

Comment: The way to solve this is to make the code smaller and smaller until you find the exact location of the problem. In other words: please create a minimal example. While this does take some effort, it is _the_ way to solve the problem, and anyone answering your question would have to do it. Therefore, please try to do it on your own first. See here: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/12

Comment: `Unprotect[C]` <- This is a very bad idea and it _does_ break stuff. Even if it is not responsible for the specific issue you are asking about, it will prevent some people from evaluating your code and try to help you.

Comment: @Szabolcs I get that `A1` and `A2` are empty when `j` is an integer greater than one. I believe this is since the lower bound of `A1` and `A2` is greater than the upper bound of `A1` and `A2`.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68130980/10426870).

Comment: What do you want to happen when `Length[A]==0`? You have `N[Length[Intersection[A, C]]/Length[A]]` so of course you can expect that error when `A` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as intended. As others have mentioned in the comments, your code could use some cleaning up. But the basic issue is when $j>1$ both `A1` and `A2` are empty (the bounds on your table are trivial). That means `Intersection[A1, A2]` is empty so `A` is empty and `Length[A]==0`. This gives `g1 = N[Length[Intersection[A, C]]/Length[A]]` $=$ Something$/0$ which gives your error. So the question is, what do you want `g1` to be when `Length[A]==0`? Whatever you want to do, you can accomplish it simply by doing

```
g1 = If[Length[A]>0, N[Length[Intersection[A,C]]/Length[A]], 
   "Whatever you want. Some value, raise an error, abort, ...etc."];
```